# How to avoid reading repeatly the data in the data transmission by tcp/ip ssh tunnel?

Tags: c++, matlab, tcp

I use the tcp/ip ssh tunnel to send a vector containing 120000 numbers of type double from my computer to a server. Every time I send 250 numbers. Thus, I send 120000/250=480 times. To ensure the server revieving correctly my data, evecry time the server recieves 250 numbers and then sends them back. In my computer, I use Matlab. In the server, I use c++.

I compare the sent vector and the recieved vector. They are not the same. After some same number, the recieved vector starts repeats the elements before then continue show the elements later. For example: sent vector:123456789, recieved vector:123454567

Ynew is the sent vector and Yrecieve is the recieved vector, matlab code:

```
tcp = tcpip('127.0.0.1', 54321, 'NetworkRole', 'server');

linput=250;

set(tcp, 'OutputBufferSize', 8*linput);
set(tcp, 'InputBufferSize', 8*linput);

Yrecieve=zeros(size(Ynew));

fopen(tcp);

i=0;
while(i<length(Ynew))    
    din=Ynew(i+1:i+linput);
    while(sum(isnan(swapbytes(din)))~=0)
        din(isnan(swapbytes(din)))=din(isnan(swapbytes(din)))*1.00001;
    end
    fwrite(tcp, swapbytes(din), 'double');

    dout = fread(tcp, linput, 'double');
    Yrecieve(i+1:i+linput)=swapbytes(dout);    

    i=i+linput;
end

fclose(tcp);
```

c++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <math.h>

extern "C"
void useCUDA();

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

using namespace std;



int main()
{

    vector<double> Y;

    int lread = 250, nMu = 4, ltotal = 120000;

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(54321);
    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));


    double* block_buffer_input;
    block_buffer_input = new double[lread];
    double* block_buffer_output;
    block_buffer_output = new double[lread];

    int Ylength = Y.size();

    while (Y.size() < ltotal)
    {

        while (Y.size() == Ylength)
        {
            read(sock, reinterpret_cast<char*>(block_buffer_input), lread * sizeof(double));
            Y.insert(Y.end(), &block_buffer_input[0], &block_buffer_input[lread]);
        }

        Ylength = Y.size();

        int Sp = Y.size() - lread;
        for (int i = 0; i != lread; ++i)
        {
            block_buffer_output[i] = Y[Sp + i];
        }
        write(sock, (char*)block_buffer_output, lread * sizeof(double));



    }


    delete[] block_buffer_input;
    delete[] block_buffer_output;
    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

How to change my c++ code to make the recieve vector the same as the sent one?

Comment: `while (Y.size() == Ylength)` ?why this condition? with tcp you can never be sure that you get all the data at once, but instead you have to read what you get and continue until you got all the data

Comment: Yes, you r right. But I change it to while (Y.size() != Ylength+lread), I still can not get the same vector.

Comment: I didnt claim that you can fix your problem by adding a `!`. I just noted that this is something that I do not understand. Also `(Y.size != Ylength + lread)` is a condition i do not understand. You have to look at the value returned from `read` otherwise you have no chance to interpret the received data in a meaningful way

Comment: `lread` is what you expect to read (is it?), but currently you ignore the number of bytes that were actually read

Comment: Every time, I send lread=250 numbers. If it do not put the 250 number in the vector Y, it cannot continue the next loop.

Comment: `read` does not always read 250 numbers. Thats what I am trying to tell you... You need to look at the value returned from `read` to know how many bytes were actually read

Comment: Yes, lread=250 is the quantity of number I want to read in every loop.

Comment: so you have to call `read` in a loop and count how many numbers each call received until you have the amount you expect. Currently you assume each call to `read` would write `lread` numbers into the buffer which is not always the case

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. while (Y.size() != Ylength+lread) makes sure that if the size Y do not increase 250, il will continue to read the number.

Comment: sorry, but I dont know anymore how else to explain. Please read the documentation of `read` and pay attention to the return value. It is important in order to use `read` correctly, but currently you ignore it

Comment: Thanks! I will read the documentation of read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `read` you need to use its return value to know how many bytes actually have been received. In your code you assume that for each call you get `lread = 250` numbers

```
read(sock, reinterpret_cast<char*>(block_buffer_input), lread * sizeof(double));
Y.insert(Y.end(), &block_buffer_input[0], &block_buffer_input[lread]);
```

However, `read` may have read only a single byte or two or more... In that case you still insert old garbage from `block_buffer_input` into the vector. Lets say only 100 numbers have been read by `read` and written into the buffer then you still copy till `&block_buffer_input[lread]`.

Instead your code should look more like this:

```
size_t bytes_expected = xy;
size_t bytes_read = 0;
while (bytes_read < bytes_expected) {        
   auto r = read(sock,buffer,bytes_expected);  // last parameter is just the maximum, but less might be read
   // copy only that part of the buffer that contains valid data
   Y.insert(Y.end(),buffer.begin(),buffer.begin()+r);
   bytes_read += r;
}
```

This is just to outline the basic idea, hope it helps.

Comment: @TomY well I realized that the code was wrong. See edit for the fix

Comment: The one before was the outline of your basic idea. I have got what you want to say. It is really nice of you to add the part for the insertion of vector Y. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Excuse me, I have another question in the same background, but about completing the package. If you are available, would you please answer this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56019820/how-to-know-the-memcpy-function-has-successfully-copied-the-memory-during-comp)