# How to know the memcpy() function has successfully copied the memory during completing pakage?

Tags: c++, tcp

I send a vector containing 120000 from my computer to a server by tcp/ip ssh tunnel. Every time, I send 250 values of type double and the sever send me back them to ensure that I have sent the data correctly. I use the function read() to recieve the data in the server.  As we know, read() cannot always recieve all the 250 values (250*8=2000bytes) in one time. Thus, I use the function memcpy() to save the recieved data until it reach 2000 bytes. However, the memcpy only work one times.

For example, I send 250 values (2000bytes). The server recieves 1408 bytes in the 1st time. I use memcpy() to save these 1406 bytes into a array from the buffer.  The server recieves 594 bytes in the 2nd time. I use memcpy() to save these 592 bytes into the same array from the buffer. However, I find the 2nd time, memcpy() does not work according to the value send back from server to my computer.

The code c++ in server has two objectives:
1. recieve the 250 data every times.
2. send them back every times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <math.h>

extern "C"
void useCUDA();

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

using namespace std;



int main()
{

    vector<double> Y;

    int lread = 250, nMu = 4, ltotal = 120000;


    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));  
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(54321); 
    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));


    double* block_buffer_input;
    block_buffer_input = new double[lread];
    double* block_input;
    block_input = new double[lread];
    double* block_buffer_output;
    block_buffer_output = new double[lread];


    while (Y.size() < ltotal)
    {
        int nbyteread = 0;
        int nbytereadtimes = 0;

        while (nbyteread < 8 * lread)
        {

            nbytereadtimes = read(sock, reinterpret_cast<char*>(block_buffer_input), lread * sizeof(double));


            memcpy(block_input + nbyteread, block_buffer_input, nbytereadtimes);

            if (nbytereadtimes != 8 * lread && nbytereadtimes != 0)
                cout << Y.size() << ": " << nbytereadtimes << " " << block_input + nbyteread <<endl;


            nbyteread += nbytereadtimes;
        }

        Y.insert(Y.end(), &block_input[0], &block_input[lread]);

        cout << Y.size() << ": " << nbyteread << endl;


        int Sp = Y.size() - lread;
        for (int i = 0; i != lread; ++i)
        {
            block_buffer_output[i] = Y[Sp + i];
        }
        write(sock, (char*)block_buffer_output, lread * sizeof(double));



    }


    delete[] block_buffer_input;
    delete[] block_input;
    delete[] block_buffer_output;
    close(sock);


    return 0;
}
```

I want to know why the memcpy() do not work in the 2nd time.

Comment: 'Do not work' is not a problem description, but you aren't error-testing the result of any system calls here.

Comment: Because every time, I send back the 250 values received in the server, I can check their values in my computer. I find that if it takes two times read() the data, the second time read() data is not correct. The second time read() data are the same as previous 250 values.

Comment: For example: the first 250 values(from the 1st element to the 250th in vector), I read all of them one time, they are correct. the second 250 values (from the 251th to the 500th in vector), I read all of them two times: 176 elements and 74 elements. The 176 elements are correct (from the 251th to the 426th in vector). However, the 74 elements are not. They should be from the 427th to the 500th elements in vector. But now they are the 177th to the 250th elements in vector.

Comment: I think that this means the memcpy() do not work in the 2nd time.

Comment: I don't care what you can do in your computer. Any code that doesn't error-check system calls is wrong by definition. You also aren't testing for end of stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you adding nbyteread to the pointer to an array of doubles  you actually referring to address of nbyteread * sizeof(double) (address of nbyteread element)

```
memcpy(block_input + nbyteread, block_buffer_input, nbytereadtimes);
```

Comment: No. You should use char* block_input